# asp:textbox force numeric keypad on Internet Explorer Metro

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, windows-8

On a touchscreen PC, when using the Metro Internet explorer,

Is there any way to force the numeric keypad to open first when the focus is put on an asp:Testbox control ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBadge" runat="server" MaxLength="9" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; font-size: 16pt;" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Its a number only textbox and having the normal keyboard pop up when its selected is annoying for users as it slows them down.

So instead of this :
[image: Initial Touch Keyboard]

Id like this to show:
[image: Numpad & Symbol Keypad]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming IE10/Metro follows the standard approach, you need an HTML5 `<input type="number"...` in your output. If you're using .NET 4.5, you can just set `TextMode="Number"` on your `TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBadge" runat="server" TextMode="Number" ...
```

If you're using .NET 4.0, there's [an update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) which will let you specify the `type` attribute:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBadge" runat="server" type="number" ...
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 or earlier, the HTML5 input types are not supported by the built-in controls. You'll need to write a custom control to support them.